# Automator is not able to highlight text with click and drag using "Watch Me Do.action"

Tags: automator

I am using automator with the `Watch Me Do.action` to scrape text from an very old application. Everything works okay, except that when i click on text and highlight it, it wont register the highlighting of the text.

Is this not supported by the `Watch Me Do.action`? If not how do i solve it?

Comment: did you turn on "Access for assistive devices." ?

Comment: @Buscar웃, it is enabled for `Automator`.. Is there anything else i should turn on?

Comment: The mouse movement works fine, but i cant really click and highlight anything, it does not register this behavior.